# How to use a password in a gpg command

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg

I am new to linux and I am trying to do the following:

I have a folder, that I want first to compress in a tar then to encrypt it with gpg and all of this is while running a command (no interactive GUI with the machine). All I find now in the internet are GUIs that show up and ass you to type the password

```
tar -cvf archive.tar <directory>

gpg -c archive.tar <target-directory>
```

I keep reading the options of the gpg command but i don't understand how to find the equivalent of 7za :

```
7za a -p <my-password>
```

this is what I want only to insert the password as part of the command.

Do you have any pointers?
thank you

Comment: From `man 7z` on Ubuntu, I see `7z a -mhe=on -pmy_password archive.7z a_directory`

Comment: would that apply to other compression algorithms like zip?